# Prepare Ubuntu (Server no gui) on one mac for another mac using USB

Tags: server, usb-installation, macbook-air, mac-mini

I have two mac computers. One is a MacMini 2010, the other is a Macbook Ari 2019. Both have intel chips. I want to prepare a new installation of ubuntu with a few things and services and use the prepared disk in my mac mini. As my mac mini is doing controlling thinks, i can not shutdown it and do the installation on the final hardware.
So i want to prepare the disk on my macbook air, without changing anything on the Macbook Air. The idea is to use a usb case with the new disk, plug this into a port from my macbook air, and prepare the disk with a fresh bootable ubuntu server installation. Then boot up the server installation from USB attached to the Macbook Air and install all necessary services. Finally  swap the new ubuntu installation disk with the disk currently running in my Mac Mini.

Is this possible and how can it be done?